# Random multipliers of polynomial values at known points in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation

Scenario (1)

We define the polynomial ring $R[x]$ consist of all polynomial with coefficients from $\mathbb Z_p$, where $p$ is a prime number. Let $P_i$ be a polynomial such that $P_i \in R[x]$. We evaluate $P_1$ at many  $X= (x_1,...,x_n)$ to obtain $Y^{(1)}=(y_1,...,y_n)$, where $n$ can we very large and far more greater than $d+1$, where $d$ is the polynomial degree. We multiply each element in $Y^{(1)}$ by the distinct value chosen uniformly at random from $\mathbb Z_p$, and we denote the result by $Y'^{(1)}=(y_1 \times r_1,...,y_n \times r_n)$, where $r_i$ are random value picked uniformly from $\mathbb Z_p$. The roots of this polynomial matter to us, therefore if one can recover the original polynomial, $P_1$, or by any means he recovers the root(s) (or any knowledge of the roots) our protocol is broken. We publish the $X= (x_1,...,x_n)$ and $Y'^{(1)}$, so anybody can access them (including those who wants to try to figure out the original polynomial and its roots).

Questions 1:

### - Given $X$ and  $Y'^{(1)}$'s, can anybody deduce any information  about the original polynomial (e.g. the roots of the polynomial or the degree of the polynomial, etc)?

Scenario (2)

We have many (millions) of polynomials  $P_i$ and we evaluate all of them at the same $X= (x_1,...,x_n)$, to obtain $Y^{(1)},..., Y^{(n)}$. Similar to the scenario (1), we multiply each element in $Y^{(i)}$ by a distinct uniformly at random value $r_i$ (i.e. note all $r_i$'s are random for all elements in all  $Y_i$'s) to obtain $Y'^{(1)},..., Y'^{(n)}$.

Questions 2:

- Given $X$ and  all $Y'^{(i)}$, can anybody deduce any information  about the original polynomial (e.g. the root(s) or the degree of these polynomials)?

Remark: The main reason that the scenario(2) is different than (1) is that the $Y'^{(i)}$'s are somehow linked to each other, as all are the result of evaluation of different polynomials at the same $X$ values. So this may give enough advantage to whoever wants to figure out some information about the original polynomials.

Question 3: If we evaluate a polynomial on some $X$'s to obtain some $Y$ values, Why multiplying $Y$'s by distinct random values is not equal to multiplying the original polynomial by another polynomial?

Question 4: Assume we have $f(x)=(x−1)(x−3)$ interpolate at $X(10,11,12,13,14)$ to obtain $Y=(63,80,99,120,156)$ pick some random value $r=(2,7,6,8,10)$ and compute $Y′=(126,560,594,960,1430)$. Pick prime $p$ at your choice. So we should be able to interpolate a polynomial with $Y′$ and $X$. This polynomial should have some roots including $1$ and $3$. But in practice it is not right.
Many thanks

Comment: @hardmath Yes you right, but I mentioned in the question " the distinct" value. Thus each $Y'_i= Y_i \times r_i$ where each $r_i$ is the distinct random value.

Comment: @hardmath $Z_p$ is a ring. Well I don't know if one can infer any information about the original polynomial.

Comment: @hardmath The example added.

Comment: @hardmath I have made all changes you asked . If you don't still understand it ....

Comment: @hardmath Well, dear hardmath that is why I put this question. If I knew the answer I'd never ask. Also I cannot read the mind if you want to clarify in a particular way you need to clearly ask me to do so. In terms of your answer that is what exactly I'm wondering. Would this (multiplying the $y_i$ values by random values) imply that we have multiplied the original polynomial by a random polynomial?

Comment: The ability to determine a polynomial by interpolating a finite set of values depends on knowing the degree of the polynomial, so that we choose the right number of distinct $X_i$'s.  In your case it will be possible to interpolate the randomized new points $(X_i,Y_i*r_i)$, but it will not be true (usually) that this new interpolated polynomial is a multiple of the original polynomial.  Since you don't have a provision for introducing new ordinates $X_i$, it appears you are stuck with computing a new interpolating polynomial of degree no more than $n-1$.

Comment: A detailed example of what you are proposing would perhaps help clarify your idea.  As it stands, it appears hopeless to "recover the original polynomial".

Comment: @hardmath I'll provide some examples (which is considering a bit more complicated problem than the current question) tomorrow, definitely. Am I right (for now) to conclude that given this "interpolated polynomial" one cannot find the roots of the original polynomial with high probability?

Comment: You haven't said what distribution the random multipliers follow, or what ring "Zp" is, or how ring elements from there multiply a polynomial's values.  I believe it is clear in your thinking, but I cannot deduce these things without explicit statements from you.  The simplest case is, throw away the $Y_i$ values and what do we know?  Not enough to find the roots of the original polynomial for sure.  If one of the original $Y_i$ were zero, and if we knew that in a domain $r_i$ cannot possibly equal zero, then the fact that $Y_i' = Y_i*r_i$ is zero does tell us that $X_i$ was a root.

Comment: @hardmath I edited the entire question, hope it got clear now. Many thanks.

Comment: @kasper remove the "on hold" as the question got modified.

Comment: I see now the context more clearly, and thanks to your edits, the connection with one-time pad cryptography is evident.  I take it the prime $p$ is a large one, perhaps larger than $n$?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, it is large enough. It can even be RSA moduli $N=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are the safe primes.

Comment: Observation (1): We can interpolated product of two polynomials of degree d, having $2n+1$ points. Here we only have $n$ points, as we only have $n$ elements in each $Y'$ and $X$. Thus we cannot obtain the original polynomial or even the product original and a random polynomial due, to lack of enough points.

Comment: True.  However you can express the new polynomial as a sum of the original one and an interpolation of the values $(r_i-1)Y_i$.

Comment: @hardmath Imagine My original polynomial,$P_1$ is of degree 2. Based on the observation 1, I should be able to reconstruct (interpolate) the $P_1 \times R$, picking 5 points from $Y'$ and $X$. Here R is unknown random polynomial. So the roots of $P_1$ should be in the product, but in practice this is not true!

Comment: Where do you expect the "roots" of the polynomial to exist?  If there are roots that appear among the $X_i$, then of course these will be retained since $Y_i'=Y_i=0$.  However in general a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $p$ prime will have roots that do not exist in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @hardmath $f(x)=(x-1)(x-3)$ interpolate at $X(10,11,12,13,14)$ to obtain $Y=(63,80,99,120,156)$ pick some random value $r=(2,7,6,8,10)$ and compute $Y'=(126,560,594,960,1430)$. Pick prime $p$ at your choice. So we should be able to interpolate a polynomial with $Y'$ and $X$. This polynomial should have some roots including 1 and 3. But in practice it is not right. Please correct me if I'm wrong !

Comment: Indeed this is not right.  Perhaps you should post that directly as a new Question (you can include a link back to this one as part of the context if you wish).